# Overwriting urls in from third party lib in Django not working

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to overwrite some urls in Django, specifically in the Django Oauth2 toolkit so I can use my own view and their mixins.

Currently when a token is created from Django Oauth, it [routes](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/urls.py) the token to be [created](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/base.py#L157). So instead of it routing here I'm expecting it to route to my method and for it to print out on my command line in the Django logs.

I tried overriding the urls:

```
url(r'^oauth2/token/$', TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
url(r'^oauth2/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

However, I can't see anything showing up in my custom view:

## TokenView

```
class TokenView(CsrfExemptMixin, OAuthLibMixin, View):

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'some on in here!'
```

Is there something I'm missing about redirections?

Comment: What do you expect to show up, and when/where?

Comment: I will add more details to what and where it will show up.

Comment: Are you sure it's a `POST` request?

Comment: @knbk I'm pretty sure, it's the only place that creates the token in Django. I tried checking which routes are getting used when I create a token but I can only see the django routes used.